# CSS / JS not working on content fetched via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making an app in which cards overlap each other like "Tinder" (name just for example). This is working fine when I am fetching data normally using while loop on the same page. However, when I fetch the same data via AJAX from a different page the cards get displayed one after the other from top to bottom instead of over lapping. I don't understand if this is a problem with CSS / JS not loading on AJAX fetched contents or the problem is something else that I cannot detect because rest css styles about card design is working good but then its not overlapping anymore when AJAX is used. I tried placing the CSS and JS pages for card swipe into `cards.php` as well in a hope that returned file with JS might do the trick even though I felt that its not a good idea (still did it to check if I could catch the error) but still its not working. Tried whatever was possible for me but no luck.

Fine working code when I fetch directly:

```
<div class="stackedcards-container">
<?php
  $users = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id != :mem AND mem_sex != :sex");
  $users-> bindValue(':mem', $sessionUser);
  $users-> bindValue(':sex', $mySex);
  $users-> execute();

  while($a = $users->fetch()){
?>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="images/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="popular-destinations-text"><span class="name"><?php echo $a['mem_fname']; ?></span> <br/> <small><?php echo $userAge; ?>, <?php echo ucfirst($a['mem_sex']); ?> &middot; <?php echo $distData; ?></small> <br/> <small>Siliguri, West Bengal, IN</small></div>
      <div class="popular-destinations-images">
        <div class="circle"><img src="images/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
        <div class="circle"><img src="images/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
        <div class="circle"><img src="images/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
<div>
```

But this serves the purpose only when the page refreshes. However, I want to make it automatic. Hence, I want to scan this data and if new record exists then it should get loaded.

Here is what I tried

index.php

```
<div class="stackedcards-container">
  <div class="getcards"></div>
</div>

<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    $(".getcards").load("processes/cards.php").fadeIn("slow");
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

cards.php

```
<?php
$users = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE mem_id != :mem AND mem_sex != :sex");
  $users-> bindValue(':mem', $sessionUser);
  $users-> bindValue(':sex', $mySex);
  $users-> execute();

while($a = $users->fetch()) {
?>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-image"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gQsq07/Adventure_and_Outdoor.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <div class="popular-destinations-text"><span class="name"><?php echo $a['mem_fname']; ?></span> <br/> <small><?php echo $userAge; ?>, <?php echo ucfirst($a['mem_sex']); ?> &middot; <?php echo $distData; ?></small> <br/> <small>Siliguri, West Bengal, IN</small></div>
    <div class="popular-destinations-images">
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jmEYL7/adventure_1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nsCynn/adventure_2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/hmsL07/adventure_3.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

When I perform this method, the cards get displayed but does not follow the usual overlapping method as in the 1st working code. The cards get displayed one after the other all at once from top to bottom (like usual table records). How can achieve the similar result as I am getting in the working code via AJAX ?

Also, if I have a feeling that since fetching contents from a different page is not working, loading contents from the same page "might" work. If that's possible, please help me load the contents from the same page. We can give it a shot (if possible) to check if its working. I tried it like this below but that didn't seem to work.

index.php

```
<div class="stackedcards-container">
  <div class="getcards"></div>
</div>

<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    $(".getcards").load("index.php .stackedcards-container").fadeIn("slow");
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I am adding Screenshots for clear reference.

Screenshot 1: Working fine when NOT using AJAX. See the two cards overlapping each other.

[image]

Screenshot 2: Overlapping not working when using AJAX. Cards gets displayed top to bottom.

[image]

Comment: promises have nothing to do with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a CSS issue ? can you provide screenshot ?

Your content fetched by ajax should behave the same way.
The only thing I see is that you have an extra container when using ajax **stackedcards-container**. Is it possible that your layout issue is related to that ?

ex:

```
body > .cards
```

or

```
body { width:100%; height:100%; }
# stackedcards-container missing styles and not expending
```

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please check.

Comment: `stackedcards-container` is not an extra container. Its there already. I have added it in the first working code to make it clear. Please check.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. You're using a JS library to deal with your content ? Just imagine this : You using a carousel library. Then you edit content after library initialization... your library might not detect the new items (not yet processed). If you're using a library, check the doc to know if there is a way to force the render.

Comment: That can't be called a library. I found it on codepen created by some random guy. So there isn't any manual to it. Also, what you are saying can't be the solution my experience says. There is something else I need to deal with here.

Comment: put your example on a sandbox, I'll find the problem in few seconds. (or give a link to the codepen library / not-library)

Comment: can you connect with me using Team Viewer or Anydesk? I guess that's a better idea. You can directly work on my code that way. Everything is already setup here. Would be easier for you.

Comment: I couldn't find the library on codepen. Don't remember where I got it. AnyDesk is very small software please download it. I am giving you my address to connect with. You can work on my computer. Don't worry, it won't allow me to use your computer. However, you can use mine to work on my code.

Comment: I'm not going to fix it for you lol I'll let you know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for you time. I will find a way out myself.